# Merge tags [alternation] and [regex-alternation]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

We have two separate tags [alternation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alternation) (created in 2013) and [regex-alternation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex-alternation) (created in 2014) with identical descriptions. Why is the latter not a synonym of the first?

Comment: I don't think we need either of these tags.

Comment: While the tag wiki might disagree, [tag:alternation] is used for quite a bit of other stuff as well, suggesting that it shouldn't be merged with the regex specific meaning. A burnitation/cleanup without synonym might however be a good idea. (For cleanup one would have to decide on a meaning thou.)

Comment: @MegaIng Are there any examples of tagging something with [tag:alternation] that aren't suitable for [tag:regex-alternation] and should exist?  (ie, an area of expertise that someone could reasonably have, or the like)  I don't think we have people who are experts on, say, drawing chess boards.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Not really I think? At least none for which I just found a question in the tagged list. We can just burnitatie it (or make it a synonym).